# How do print the query which is built using search api

Tags: search, views

I have created a view using search api now i just want to print my query.But when i used hook_views_pre_execute(){
   dpq($view->build_info['query']);
}
it does not show my query.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Views query preview in **Views Settings** (`admin/structure/views/settings`) by checking the box "**Show SQL query"**.

Then you will be able to see the query created by your view while you constructing it.
[image]

Comment: thaks for your response to my post. but i have already fallowed these step ,its shows blank no query.

Comment: @Clive Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Search API does *not* show the query in views preview, which is [a known bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2769021).

A fix has been committed to the dev release, but it's not yet in the current stable 1.20 release.

Comment: Now it has been almost 4 years. Still, the SearchAPI doesn't show the query in views preview.